# Android DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener constantly fires while spinning

Tags: android, datepicker

Android's `DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener` constantly keeps firing while the user is spinning the calendar. I think this has changed in recent Android versions. Previously it only fired after the spinner stopped.

I would like to update content based on the new date, which involves web-access so this is too slow (and wasteful) to do on every event.

I prefer not to use a separate dialog to choose the date and update my content on the close-event of that dialog.

**How do I know (trigger an event) when the datepicker has stopped spinning?** 
I can think of some mechanism with timers to check if the date is changed in, let’s say, the last second, but this looks pretty complex to me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, by re-starting a `CountDownTimer` on every `OnDateChangedListener`-event. The timer is only 500 ms.

As long as the user is scrolling `CountDownTimer` will not finish. It is just constantly canceled and started on every `OnDateChangedListener`-event, until `DatePicker` is not scrolling anymore (not for 500 ms that is).